# Batch Search for IDs with Twitter API

Tags: twitter

For twitter I'm querying tweets through its search and storing that tweet data on a local server. But metrics such as number of retweets, number of favorites, etc is something that can change over time.

So at a later point in time, I want to go back and check how those tweets have changed, except Twitter has a rate limit on the number of request. This means I cannot do each tweets individually. Is there a way that I can batch search tweets based on their ids so I do not reach the rate limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question I received from the Twitter Forums, no this is not possible.